# Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am making a simple application that lets me operate on sets. The demand is for it to hold the set data in a dynamic array. However, I am having a problem that I can't narrow down.

Sets.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SetArray.h"


int main()


{

int a1[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int a2[] = { 5,6,7,8 };

SetArray arr1 = SetArray(a1, (sizeof(a1) / sizeof(*a1)));
SetArray arr2 = SetArray(a2, (sizeof(a2) / sizeof(*a2)));
arr2.printSet();

SetArray arr3 = arr1 + arr2;
arr3.printSet();

return 0;
}
```

SetArray.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
class SetArray
{
public:

SetArray(int * elems, int count);
~SetArray();

friend SetArray operator+(SetArray &set1, SetArray &set2);

int * getArray();
int getArraySize();
void printSet();
int * elemsArray;
private:

int count = 0;
};
```

SetArray.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SetArray.h"


SetArray::SetArray(int * elems, int count)
{
    elemsArray = elems;
    SetArray::count = count;

}


SetArray::~SetArray()
{
}

int * SetArray::getArray()
{
    return elemsArray;
}

int SetArray::getArraySize()
{
    return count;

}

void SetArray::printSet() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << elemsArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

SetArray operator+(SetArray & set1, SetArray & set2)
{
std::vector<int> vector1;
std::vector<int> vector2;

for (int x = 0; x < set1.count; x++)
{
    vector1.push_back(set1.elemsArray[x]);
}
for (int x = 0; x < set2.count; x++)
{
    vector2.push_back(set2.elemsArray[x]);
}

if (vector1.size() >= vector2.size())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vector2.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (std::find(vector1.begin(), vector1.end(), vector2[i]) == vector1.end())
        {
            vector1.push_back(vector2[i]);
        }
    }

    int * dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = new int(vector1.size());

    for (int j = 0; j < vector1.size(); j++)
    {
        dynamicArray[j] = vector1[j];
    }

    return SetArray(dynamicArray, vector1.size());



}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (std::find(vector2.begin(), vector2.end(), vector1[i]) == vector2.end())
        {
            vector2.push_back(vector1[i]);
        }
    }

    int * dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = new int(vector2.size());

    for (int j = 0; j < vector2.size(); j++)
    {
        dynamicArray[j] = vector2[j];
    }

    return SetArray(dynamicArray, vector2.size());

    }

}
```

So, when I enter the debug code, program ends with such error, despite showing correct results on a console:

> HEAP[Sets.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00830000, 00854A30 )
>   Sets.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Then I try to narrow down the issue by manually executing the code line by line, nothing happens, no error shows, program executes correctly.

Then when I try to run it without debugging, once again, the correct data shows in the console, however program ends with an "Application Sets.exe has stopped working"

I believe there must be some non alocated pointer causing all the problems, but I cannot see where the problem lays. Could you please help me?

Comment: You design seems weird, you use `int*` to store internal elements but then you use `std::vector` to compute the sum between two `SetArray`. Why don't you just stick with `std::vector` which will manage memory for you and likely fix any issue?

Comment: I just cannot. Like I said, I need to store values of the set in a dynamic array. I just chose vector to manipulate the data, because it's more convenient.

Comment: Actually a `std::vector` is a dynamic array. In any case you are passing a stack allocated `int[]` to the `SetArray` you create, this will create dangling pointers when exiting the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dynamicArray = new int(vector1.size());
```

Very small typo. This should be

```
dynamicArray = new int[vector1.size()];
```

Ditto for the other `new` allocation as well.

Also, your class, as designed, is going to leak memory. But that would be a different question.

P.S. I could not immediately see the bug either. The code looked fine to me, at a first glance. But it took less than a minute to find it, in my debugger. You should spent some time learning how to use a debugger. It'll help you find bugs in your code, instead of having to wait for random strangers to help you, on stackoverflow.com